# TYPO3 Extbase backend module TypoScript for Fluid layout not loading

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-extensions

In TYPO3 CMS 6.2.17, I used Extension Builder to make an Extbase extension that has a frontend plugin and a backend module. I built a localhost website with two pages: id=1 is a standard page; and id=2 is a folder. The standard page has the site's root TypoScript template, and that template includes my extension's static file.

I activated my Extbase extension in the Web module. When I selected my extension and the folder page (id=2), I saw a populated listing display from the default controller and action; but the display was using the frontend Fluid layout, not the backend layout. I want the backend layout for its Fluid actionMenu in the "typo3-docheader-functions" div class.

I can't seem to get the backend Fluid layout for the display. I've selected the standard page (empty listing display as expected) and even the site root page (id=0) (also empty listing display), but they both use the frontend Fluid layout, too.

I've cleared all caches and cleaned typo3temp/ in the Install Tool. I've deactivated and reactivated my extension in Extension Manager. I've tried solutions suggested in [TYPO3 Extbase backend module. Template path issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807390/typo3-extbase-backend-module-template-path-issue/33911885) and even [TYPO3 4.5 extbase test backend module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343527/typo3-4-5-extbase-test-backend-module?rq=1). Nothing has worked so far. I've even gone through the site's Install Tool "all configuration" settings, but saw nothing I thought could affect the backend display problem.

The code is straight from Extension Builder, but here are some excerpts.

ext_tables.php:

```
if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE') {

    /**
     * Registers a Backend Module
     */
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule(
        'MyVendor.' . $_EXTKEY,
        'web',
        'myextbe',  // Submodule key
        '',                     // Position
        array(
            'Import' => 'list, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
            'Pages' => 'list, show',
        ),
        array(
            'access' => 'user,group',
            'icon'   => 'EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/ext_icon.gif',
            'labels' => 'LLL:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_myextbe.xlf',
        )
    );

}

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile($_EXTKEY, 'Configuration/TypoScript', 'My Ext');
```

myext\Configuration\TypoScript\constants.txt:

```
module.tx_myext_myextbe {
    view {
        # cat=module.tx_myext_myextbe/file; type=string; label=Path to template root (BE)
        templateRootPath = EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/
        # cat=module.tx_myext_myextbe/file; type=string; label=Path to template partials (BE)
        partialRootPath = EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Backend/Partials/
        # cat=module.tx_myext_myextbe/file; type=string; label=Path to template layouts (BE)
        layoutRootPath = EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Backend/Layouts/
    }
    persistence {
        # cat=module.tx_myext_myextbe//a; type=string; label=Default storage PID
        storagePid =2
    }
}
```

myext\Configuration\TypoScript\setup.txt:

```
 # Module configuration
module.tx_myext_myextbe {
    persistence {
        storagePid = {$module.tx_myext_myextbe.persistence.storagePid}
    }
    view {
        templateRootPath = {$module.tx_myext_myextbe.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPath = {$module.tx_myext_myextbe.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPath = {$module.tx_myext_myextbe.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace all `module.tx_myext_myextbe` to `module.tx_myext` and `plugin.tx_myext_myextfe` to `plugin.tx_myext`.

`module.tx_myext_myextbe` is invalid notation in 6.2.x - in the result Extbase can't find it and tries the default template path which is frontend one

**constants.txt**

```
module.tx_myext {
    view {
        # cat=module.tx_myext/file; type=string; label=Path to template root (BE)
        templateRootPath = EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/
        # cat=module.tx_myext/file; type=string; label=Path to template partials (BE)
        partialRootPath = EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Backend/Partials/
        # cat=module.tx_myext/file; type=string; label=Path to template layouts (BE)
        layoutRootPath = EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Backend/Layouts/
    }
    persistence {
        # cat=module.tx_myext//a; type=string; label=Default storage PID
        storagePid = 2
    }
}
```

**setup.txt**

```
module.tx_myext {
    persistence {
        storagePid = {$module.tx_myext.persistence.storagePid}
    }
    view {
        templateRootPath = {$module.tx_myext.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPath = {$module.tx_myext.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPath = {$module.tx_myext.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
}
```

**TypoScript Object browser**

```
[module]
  [tx_myext]
   [view]
    [templateRootPath] = EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/
    [partialRootPath] = EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Backend/Partials/
    [layoutRootPath] = EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Backend/Layouts/
```

Comment: This worked! I had trusted Extension Builder's TypoScript build, and didn't even think to check its TypoScript notation for `plugin.tx_myext` and `module.tx_myext`.

Comment: That 'experiment' costed me two days of frustration some time ago ;) happy it helped you.

Comment: Please switch to `templateRootPaths` etc. (note plural "s") in all projects after TYPO3 6.2. Singular path formats are, although possibly supported, completely deprecated. Examples are correct for 6.2 but not after that!